# First time making fudge. Will it be okay if I forgot to add vanilla?

Tags: chocolate, fudge

My mom always made chocolate fudge, unfortunately I never learned how she did it. I tried making it for the first time and I forgot to put the vanilla in. Will this be okay. Should I toss it and start over?

Comment: Try some and see is the only way to know if a recipe really works, so no, don't toss it.

Answer (score 6):

Vanilla is not an essential ingredient in fudge. The essential ingredients are sugar (or an equally calorie-rich sugar substitute like corn syrup), milk and butter. Everything else you might find in a fudge recipe is just added to modify the basic flavor, texture and/or color. There are lots of fudge recipes around which don't use vanilla at all (it's a treat which is very open to experimentation in general).

So if you don't add vanilla, it won't taste like vanilla, but that doesn't necessarily mean it will taste bad, have the wrong consistency or behave differently when cooked and cooled. It's certainly worth a try to complete the recipe, even if just to collect some experience with the non-trivial phases of making fudge which are going to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot vanilla, but it was the best batch of Fantasy (Kraft) Fudge I've ever cooked. So I will not sweat it and won't tell anyone. It's like, do you prefer mocha or vanilla Starbucks? Both types are different and very good.

Answer (score 0):

it's gonna be ok;

vanilla is usually not used in large quantity in recipes.

You might feel there's something missing, but it will still be good

Comment: Vanilla is kinda like bacon to those that like bacon.  Everything is better with it, but in most things if you leave it out you probably won't even miss it unless someone tells you it is not there.  I am someone who tends to not measure vanilla and end up putting in 2 or 3 times as much as called for because I like it.  But if I forget, no one notices in most things like fudge.